# Riemann Integral, show $f(x) \in R(x)$ on $ [0,2]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image: Riemann]

Here is my question and a solution I found online. Why did they include an extra point? Going on the basis that $f$ is integrable then $f \in R(x)$ and $L(P,f) = U(P,f)$.Is this an acceptable answer as they do not show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists$ a partition $P$ s.t.  $U(P,f) - L(P,f) \leq \epsilon$ or is it assumed in one of their steps or even in the question.

---

Apologies if this is hard to understand as this is new to me and I don't really know how to ask questions on the topic.

Comment: They showed that there exists a partition for which $L(P,f)=U(P,f)$. Thus, $U(P,f)-L(P,f)=0<\epsilon.$

Comment: Okay, so for the first summation, are they saying splitting up the interval to $[0,1]$, then for the second summation to $[1,2]$. Then their values of 1 and 2 are from the supremum of that partition?

Comment: Yes that's what is being done.

Answer (score 1):

The original partition may not contain $1$. You'll note that they originally take an arbitrary partition of $[0,2]$. For example, it could have been $P =\{0,2\}$ which doesn't contain $1$.

We want to show that given $\epsilon>0$, there is *a* partition $P$ of $[0,2]$ so that $U(P,f)-L(P,f) < \epsilon$. If we can show that there is a partition $P$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) = 0$, then we will have certainly achieved our goal. The proof is being succinct by not stating the goal of the proof explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correct approach.

Let $\epsilon>0$ given (small).

put $r=\frac {\epsilon}{3} $.

take the partition
$$\sigma=(x_0=0,x_1=1-r,x_2=1+r,x_3=2) $$

then
$$L (f,\sigma)=1.(x_1-x_0)+1.(x_2-x_1)+2. (x_3-x_2)$$
$$=(1-r)+(1+r-1+r)+2 (2-1-r)=3-r $$

$$U (f,\sigma)=1. (1-r)+2 (1+r-1+r)+2 (2-1-r) $$
$$=3+r$$

thus
$$U (f,\sigma)-L (f,\sigma)=2r <\epsilon $$
Done!